# display cv2.VideoCapture image inside Pygame surface

Tags: python, opencv, pygame, webcam

I'm trying to use opencv (cv2) to stream a webcam feed into a pygame surface object. The problem is the colors aren't displaying correctly. I think it is the type casting, but I'm having trouble understanding the pygame surface documentation to know what it expects.

This code demonstrates what I'm talking about

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import cv2
import numpy

color=False#True#False
camera_index = 0
camera=cv2.VideoCapture(camera_index)
camera.set(3,640)
camera.set(4,480)

#This shows an image the way it should be
cv2.namedWindow("w1",cv2.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
retval,frame=camera.read()
if not color:
    frame=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.flip(frame,1,frame)#mirror the image
cv2.imshow("w1",frame)

#This shows an image weirdly...
screen_width, screen_height = 640, 480
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))

def getCamFrame(color,camera):
    retval,frame=camera.read()
    if not color:
        frame=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    frame=numpy.rot90(frame)
    frame=pygame.surfarray.make_surface(frame) #I think the color error lies in this line?
    return frame

def blitCamFrame(frame,screen):
    screen.blit(frame,(0,0))
    return screen

screen.fill(0) #set pygame screen to black
frame=getCamFrame(color,camera)
screen=blitCamFrame(frame,screen)
pygame.display.flip()

running=True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): #process events since last loop cycle
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            running=False
pygame.quit()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The ultimate goal I have is to create a small photo booth application for a DIY wedding next year. I'm new to programming, but I've managed to cobble this together. I was also trying to accomplish this with VideoCapture, which outputs a PIL, which I also couldn't get to work with the surface object. I want to use a pygame surface so I can animate and overlay count-down text, borders, etc.

Update: The issue was that the cv2 function camera.read() returns a BGR image, but the pygame.surfarray expects a RGB image. This is fixed with the line

```
frame=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Also, when converting to grayscale, the following code works:

```
frame=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
frame=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
```

So, the function getCamFrame should now be

```
def getCamFrame(color,camera):
    retval,frame=camera.read()
    frame=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    if not color:
        frame=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        frame=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
    frame=numpy.rot90(frame)
    frame=pygame.surfarray.make_surface(frame)
return frame
```

Comment: I was going to come in here and answer your question since it was listed on unanswered questions. It would probably be better to post and accept your solution as a self-answer instead of having it in the question.

Comment: You should have accepted my answer, since that solved your color problem. And not updating your question with the solution.

Comment: 9 years too late

Answer (score 2):

No the color error lies in here

```
frame=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

so for normal screen color u simply change that to

```
frame=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

That will do because it works for me

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code, but I'm only getting a picture not a movie, so i copied

```
frame=getCamFrame(color,camera)
screen=blitCamFrame(frame,screen)
pygame.display.flip()
```

into a while loop, it worked but then the video was flipped, to fix it i added `cv2.flip(frame,1,frame) # mirror the image` 
before 
`frame=numpy.rot90(frame)` in `getcamFrame` function and now everything works fine.

Sorry for the poor English.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

to adapt it in your code ...

```
windowSurface = screen  #or use directly variable screen

    # convert windowSurface to cv2 ------------------------------------
    view = pygame.surfarray.array3d(windowSurface)
    #  convert from (width, height, channel) to (height, width, channel)
    view = view.transpose([1, 0, 2])
    #  convert from rgb to bgr
    img_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(view, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    cv2.imshow('windowname',img_bgr)
    cv2.waitKey(10)
```